# Multiple URL aliases for same node

Tags: nodes, path-aliases

I have the following URL aliases for the same node.

- /products/single-room/product-listing/wall-mount
- /products/multi-room/product-listing/wall-mount

I have two details button Single & Multi-rooms; Single Room button has a link to /products/single-room/product-listing/wall-mount and Multi Room button has a link to /products/multi-room/product-listing/wall-mount. When I click on Single Room or Multi Room Button, both will redirect to /products/multi-room/product-listing/wall-mount; when I delete the multi-room alias the single-room button will go to /products/single-room/product-listing/wall-mount which is correct but multi-room will give the *404 not found* error.

What I need is to have two aliases for same node: When users click on single, they are redirect to the same node with /products/single-room/product-listing/wall-mount as URL; when users click on multi-room, they get redirected to the same node with /products/multi-room/product-listing/wall-mount as URL.

Please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module.  This module is specifically built to do the behavior you are describing, because search engines like it.

Unless you are using those path segments as contextual filters somewhere, there should be no reason to do this.  If you are using those path segments as contextual filters, there should be a better way to do this.  Either a view page or a panel page would be able to hold that page open, use wildcards for those address segments, and get the functionality that you want without having to upset the search engine bots.